# how long before dump files are available for download from WinQual

Tags: winqual

this is my first time using WinQual/WER to gather dump files for release builds and it appears that everything is working.  the last step is to download the dump files from the WinQual  hotlist page for a product.  on this page there are event IDs with associated Cab Icons for the dump files, the icons say "no files currently available (in collection mode)"

The status of the Cab icons have not changed in 4hours, is it normal to take this long? Or rather how long does it normally take?

just curious.

Comment: The minimum suggestion I've seen is 4 days for the error to appear in windqual.  Also this seems to be a bit eratic and 2 weeks seems to be a better bet.  As Abfo says it then depends on how often the error occurs and if you've manually requested cab files on the website.

Answer (score 1):

It can take days, or weeks, or months or never happen. Depends on the crash. If it happens infrequently then you may never see a cab. If it's a common crash then they should show up pretty quickly.

If you have any icons that show a red cross click the icon to switch to collection mode so you don't miss a cab.

See http://www.stackhash.com/WinQual/WinQual-Usage.aspx for more help on cab collection options.

Comment: Good to know, now I can move on to other problems. 

I had a suspicion when nothing showed up after two minutes that, assuming I implemented everything correctly, I might be waiting days, weeks or months.  Funny that such a potentially long delay isn't more clearly documented in WinQual help.

Thanks for the response!